# Capturar dados após o caractere # na URL do navegador

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, url

Tenho a seguinte URL `http://urldosite.u/home#6` que quando passo para uma variável, ele simplesmente anula tudo que estiver depois do **#**. E eu quero muito pegar justamente o que esta após este e este caractere, no exemplo, o número **6**

Já tentei de várias formas e não consegui nada.

```
$sitehost = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; 
$siteuri = urldecode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); 
$sitescript = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']; 
$siteparametro = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; 
$siteprotocolo = (strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']),'https') === false) ? 'http' : 'https'; $siteurl = $siteprotocolo.'://'.$sitehost.'/';
```

Comment: Poste seu código onde você faz a atribuição na variável.

Comment: Este código abaixo funciona perfeitamente para tudo o que tenho feito até agora, não tive dificuldades alguma de fazer tudo o que preciso, mas para capturar o # na url do navegador, não está funcionando

 $sitehost = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
 $siteuri = urldecode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
 $sitescript = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
 $siteparametro = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
 $siteprotocolo = (strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']),'https') === false) ? 'http' : 'https';
 $siteurl = $siteprotocolo.'://'.$sitehost.'/';

Comment: achou alguma coisa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você nunca vai conseguir usar o PHP para capturar a hash pois eles não são repassados pelo navegador. As hash não são passadas para o server, são interpretadas pelo navegador apenas como 'localização' na página.

> http://urldosite.u/home#6
>   Na prática vai mover a janela ate o elemento de ID:6

Você só vai conseguir pegar usando js.
Veja se o link ajuda: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1822617/769082

> http://urldosite.u/home#clientes
>   Usando JS para capturar a hash, você vai pode carregar a página clientes

Comment: isso eh exatamente o que procuro, eu quero enviar para uma variavel o que tem depois da hash, ou seja, anular tudo antes home#123456789 e pegar so o 123456789, mesmo digitando qualquer coisa antes da hash, com js seria possivel? irei procurar no link, muito grato

Comment: Como disse, o PHP não recebe a hash (infelizmente), SOMENTE com JS covê pode capturar - basta ver o Gmail, Twitter e outros. O link tem apenas um exemplo, talvez superficial demais, mas serve para base

Comment: Leia(m) com atenção minha resposta que você(s) vai(ão) ver que é possível SIM obter o valor de um hash com PHP. Você não vai conseguir pegar o símbolo do hash (#), mas isso se resolve com uma concatenação simples.

Comment: mas você está informando a url `$url = http://urldosite.u/home#6` e nem de longe foi o que ele pediu... ele quer capturar a url currente do navegador

Comment: exatamente como o PapaCharlie falou, no seu caso @BrunoAugusto , eu tenho que informar a URL manualmente, e quero pegar no navegador e enfiar na variável. no caso vi como faz em JS agora tenho que passar a variável js para a variável php, obrigado a todos.

Comment: Não esqueça de dar a questão como resolvida.

Comment: Mas isso não foi dito no tópico original. Com aquilo que foi apresentado, desenvolvi minha resposta assumindo que a URL era manualmente informado ao programa. Em nenhum momento foi dito que a URL a ser analsada deveria ser aquela visível no browser. *Dados! Dados! Preciso de dados! Não posso fazer tijolos sem barro!*

Comment: Verdade, mas eu percebi pelo primeiro comentário onde ele usa `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` - imaginei que queria capturar a url do browser

Answer (score 3):

Com [parse_url()](http://www.php.net/parse_url) você consegue essa e muitas outras informações sobre uma dada URL:

```
<?php

$url = 'http://urldosite.u/home#6';

print '<pre>'; print_r( parse_url( $url ) );
```

Esse pequeno fragmento te retornaria:

```
Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => urldosite.u
    [path] => /home
    [fragment] => 6
)
```

Você precisa o índice **fragment**. Se as outras informações não precisarem ser utilizadas de nenhuma outra forma, você informar como sgeundo argumento para função a constante nativa **PHP_URL_FRAGMENT**.

Dessa forma, apenas o valor correspondente ao **fragment** será retornado. No exemplo, número 6.

Nesse caso em particular, caso não exista a parte desejada na URL de entrada, você receberia um **NULL**, o que não acontece sem o segundo argumento pois no mínimo apareceriam o **scheme** e o **host**.

A não ser que a URL esteja muito mal construída, caso em que a função retornaria **FALSE**.

---

[A pedido](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/26482/capturar-dados-ap%C3%B3s-o-caractere-de-uma-url/26484?noredirect=1#comment49321_26484) do autor do tópico, um exemplo um pouco mais estendido. Olha que cara bozinho que eu sou :P:

```
$url = 'http://urldosite.u/home#6';

$fragment = parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_FRAGMENT );

if( $fragment !== FALSE && ! is_null( $fragment ) ) {

    // Faz alguma coisa com $fragment
}
```

> Não tenho muitas informações sobre como parse_url() considera uma URL como sendo mal formulada. Esse é o único motivo de eu ter feito condições ao invés de uma.

Comment: Sempre tem um Do Contra pra negativar sem ler ou sem ao menos dizer o porquê de tê-lo feito.

Comment: Eu até cogitei de negativar sua resposta, mas logo voltei atrás porque detesto negativar alguém sem ter um motivo realmente importante para isso. Porém, até seria justificável pois a sua resposta não se relaciona com a pergunta feita e, sinto dizer, ainda propõe uma gambiarra.

Comment: no caso coloquei o código exatamente da seguinte forma

<?php

$url = 'http://localhost/home#6';

print '<pre>'; print_r(parse_url($url));

?>

funcionou, mas como eu capturo a URL que está la em cia no navegador sem comer o caractere #?

Comment: Isso é básico da programação, amigo. print_r() é uma função de depuração, não deve ser usada num caso real. Você vai atribuir o retorno de parse_url() à uma variável antes de poder trabalhar com ela. ;)

Comment: cara, se é o básico, então eu admito que estou abaixo do básico, verdade mesmo, se não for incomodo. poderia me explicar melhor? pois fiz um monte de coisas no script e o raio do caractere # não aparece de forma alguma, somente se eu escrever manualmente.

Comment: O caractere # **não vai aparecer**. Sem um segundo argumento, parse_url() vai analisar a URL e retornar cada componente separadamente. Com ele, vai retornar uma string ou um inteiro pronto para você usar. O caractere # **não é** parte do componente. Ele é um... "delimitador", o qual a função toma como base para separar o *path* (no seu caso, a expressão *home*) do fragmento em si.